# Infinite loop inside a binary search tree algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-search-tree, infinite-loop

I am working on a Binary Search Tree algorithm (called BST in the code) and whenever I run the program it just keeps running for a long time. I know this means that there is an infinite loop but I can't figure out what/where is the problem (I've been trying for a while). I've had this problem once before and never figured that out either. If anyone could help find out where the loop is, what to change it to and also explain why it causes it I would be extremely grateful for the knowledge as it would also help me for future endeavors. Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Queue; 
import java.util.ArrayDeque;


public class BST<Key extends Comparable<Key>, Value> {
private Node root;             // root of BST

private class Node {
    private Key key;           // sorted by key
    private Value val;         // associated data
    private Node left, right;  // left and right subtrees
    private int N;             // number of nodes in subtree

    public Node(Key key, Value val, int N) {
        this.key = key;
        this.val = val;
        this.N = N;
    }
}

// is the symbol table empty?
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return size() == 0;
}

// return number of key-value pairs in BST
public int size() {
    return size(root);
}

// return number of key-value pairs in BST rooted at x
private int size(Node x) {
    if (x == null) return 0;
    else return x.N;
}

/***********************************************************************
*  Search BST for given key, and return associated value if found,
*  return null if not found
***********************************************************************/
// does there exist a key-value pair with given key?
public boolean contains(Key key) {
    return get(key) != null;
}

// return value associated with the given key, or null if no such key exists
public Value get(Key key) {
    return get(root, key);
}

private Value get(Node x, Key key) {
    if (x == null) return null;
    int cmp = key.compareTo(x.key);
    if      (cmp < 0) return get(x.left, key);
    else if (cmp > 0) return get(x.right, key);
    else              return x.val;
}

/***********************************************************************
*  Insert key-value pair into BST
*  If key already exists, update with new value
***********************************************************************/
public void put(Key key, Value val) {
    if (val == null) { delete(key); return; }
    root = put(root, key, val);
    assert check();
}

private Node put(Node x, Key key, Value val) {
    if (x == null) return new Node(key, val, 1);
    int cmp = key.compareTo(x.key);
    if      (cmp < 0) x.left  = put(x.left,  key, val);
    else if (cmp > 0) x.right = put(x.right, key, val);
    else              x.val   = val;
    x.N = 1 + size(x.left) + size(x.right);
    return x;
}

/***********************************************************************
*  Delete
***********************************************************************/

public void deleteMin() {
    if (isEmpty()) throw new RuntimeException("Symbol table underflow");
    root = deleteMin(root);
    assert check();
}

private Node deleteMin(Node x) {
    if (x.left == null) return x.right;
    x.left = deleteMin(x.left);
    x.N = size(x.left) + size(x.right) + 1;
    return x;
}

public void deleteMax() {
    if (isEmpty()) throw new RuntimeException("Symbol table underflow");
    root = deleteMax(root);
    assert check();
}

private Node deleteMax(Node x) {
    if (x.right == null) return x.left;
    x.right = deleteMax(x.right);
    x.N = size(x.left) + size(x.right) + 1;
    return x;
}

public void delete(Key key) {
    root = delete(root, key);
    assert check();
}

private Node delete(Node x, Key key) {
    if (x == null) return null;
    int cmp = key.compareTo(x.key);
    if      (cmp < 0) x.left  = delete(x.left,  key);
    else if (cmp > 0) x.right = delete(x.right, key);
    else { 
        if (x.right == null) return x.left;
        if (x.left  == null) return x.right;
        Node t = x;
        x = min(t.right);
        x.right = deleteMin(t.right);
        x.left = t.left;
    } 
    x.N = size(x.left) + size(x.right) + 1;
    return x;
} 


/***********************************************************************
*  Min, max, floor, and ceiling
***********************************************************************/
public Key min() {
    if (isEmpty()) return null;
    return min(root).key;
} 

private Node min(Node x) { 
    if (x.left == null) return x; 
    else                return min(x.left); 
} 

public Key max() {
    if (isEmpty()) return null;
    return max(root).key;
} 

private Node max(Node x) { 
    if (x.right == null) return x; 
    else                 return max(x.right); 
} 

public Key floor(Key key) {
    Node x = floor(root, key);
    if (x == null) return null;
    else return x.key;
} 

private Node floor(Node x, Key key) {
    if (x == null) return null;
    int cmp = key.compareTo(x.key);
    if (cmp == 0) return x;
    if (cmp <  0) return floor(x.left, key);
    Node t = floor(x.right, key); 
    if (t != null) return t;
    else return x; 
} 

public Key ceiling(Key key) {
    Node x = ceiling(root, key);
    if (x == null) return null;
    else return x.key;
}

private Node ceiling(Node x, Key key) {
    if (x == null) return null;
    int cmp = key.compareTo(x.key);
    if (cmp == 0) return x;
    if (cmp < 0) { 
        Node t = ceiling(x.left, key); 
        if (t != null) return t;
        else return x; 
    } 
    return ceiling(x.right, key); 
} 

/***********************************************************************
*  Rank and selection
***********************************************************************/
public Key select(int k) {
    if (k < 0 || k >= size())  return null;
    Node x = select(root, k);
    return x.key;
}

// Return key of rank k. 
private Node select(Node x, int k) {
    if (x == null) return null; 
    int t = size(x.left); 
    if      (t > k) return select(x.left,  k); 
    else if (t < k) return select(x.right, k-t-1); 
    else            return x; 
} 

public int rank(Key key) {
    return rank(key, root);
} 

// Number of keys in the subtree less than x.key. 
private int rank(Key key, Node x) {
    if (x == null) return 0; 
    int cmp = key.compareTo(x.key); 
    if      (cmp < 0) return rank(key, x.left); 
    else if (cmp > 0) return 1 + size(x.left) + rank(key, x.right); 
    else              return size(x.left); 
} 

/***********************************************************************
*  Range count and range search.
***********************************************************************/
public Iterable<Key> keys() {
    return keys(min(), max());
}

public Iterable<Key> keys(Key lo, Key hi) {
    Queue<Key> queue = new ArrayDeque<Key>();
    keys(root, queue, lo, hi);
    return queue;
} 

private void keys(Node x, Queue<Key> queue, Key lo, Key hi) { 
    if (x == null) return; 
    int cmplo = lo.compareTo(x.key); 
    int cmphi = hi.compareTo(x.key); 
    if (cmplo < 0) keys(x.left, queue, lo, hi); 
    if (cmplo <= 0 && cmphi >= 0) queue.offer(x.key); 
    if (cmphi > 0) keys(x.right, queue, lo, hi); 
} 

public int size(Key lo, Key hi) {
    if (lo.compareTo(hi) > 0) return 0;
    if (contains(hi)) return rank(hi) - rank(lo) + 1;
    else              return rank(hi) - rank(lo);
}


// height of this BST (one-node tree has height 0)
public int height() { return height(root); }
private int height(Node x) {
    if (x == null) return -1;
    return 1 + Math.max(height(x.left), height(x.right));
}

/*************************************************************************
*  Check integrity of BST data structure
*************************************************************************/
private boolean check() {
    if (!isBST())            System.out.println("Not in symmetric order");
    if (!isSizeConsistent()) System.out.println("Subtree counts not consistent");
    if (!isRankConsistent()) System.out.println("Ranks not consistent");
    return isBST() && isSizeConsistent() && isRankConsistent();
}

// does this binary tree satisfy symmetric order?
// Note: this test also ensures that data structure is a binary tree since order is strict
private boolean isBST() {
    return isBST(root, null, null);
}

// is the tree rooted at x a BST with all keys strictly between min and max
// (if min or max is null, treat as empty constraint)
// Credit: Bob Dondero's elegant solution
private boolean isBST(Node x, Key min, Key max) {
    if (x == null) return true;
    if (min != null && x.key.compareTo(min) <= 0) return false;
    if (max != null && x.key.compareTo(max) >= 0) return false;
    return isBST(x.left, min, x.key) && isBST(x.right, x.key, max);
} 

// are the size fields correct?
private boolean isSizeConsistent() { return isSizeConsistent(root); }
private boolean isSizeConsistent(Node x) {
    if (x == null) return true;
    if (x.N != size(x.left) + size(x.right) + 1) return false;
    return isSizeConsistent(x.left) && isSizeConsistent(x.right);
} 

// check that ranks are consistent
private boolean isRankConsistent() {
    for (int i = 0; i < size(); i++)
        if (i != rank(select(i))) return false;
    for (Key key : keys())
        if (key.compareTo(select(rank(key))) != 0) return false;
    return true;
}


/*****************************************************************************
*  Test client
*****************************************************************************/
public static void main(String[] args) { 
    BST<String, Integer> st = new BST<String, Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; !System.out.equals(i); i++) {
        String key = System.out.toString();
        st.put(key, i);
    }
    for (String s : st.keys())
        System.out.println(s + " " + st.get(s));
}
}
```

Thank you in advance to anyone who ofers help!

Comment: That's quite a lot of code to ask strangers to debug. I'd recommend picking up a debugger and having a stab at it yourself. (Knowing how to use a debugger is an extremely valuable skills anyway, so you might as well learn it.)

Comment: Great opportunity to learn how to use a [debugger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jdb.html).

Comment: With a debugger you can let it run for a while and pause it.  Mostly it will be in a loop at this point and you see what sort of loop it is in.

Comment: Hey all, thanks for the fast feedback! I have tried to use a debugger in a previous algorithm but I had trouble even figuring out how to use it. This code is straight from the textbook, all we had to do was implement a height() method and a size() method, which I did. I figured I would post this question on this forum in hopes that an infinite loop was easily findable for an individual that was extremely knowledgeable in coding in java (if that makes any sense!) I am still studying computer science and I haven't run into this problem in previous course. I wouldn't even know what to look for

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; !System.out.equals(i); i++)
```

system out won't be ever equals an integer